# Visualising uncertainty in slope and offset for a regression line?

Tags: regression, data-visualization, uncertainty

According to a least squares fit I have performed to my data, my slope is $-0.1038±0.033$, and my offset $0.1065±0.032$.  My first idea was to visualise this by drawing three lines: $0.1065-0.1038x$, $(0.1065+0.032) - (0.1038-0.33)x$, and $(0.1065-0.032) + (0.1038+0.33)x$.  Those correspond to the 95% confidence interval.  However, the joint probability that both slope and offset are at the edge of the 95% intervals is certainly not 5%.  If the two were independent it would be closer to 0.25%, whereas in reality the joint probability is probably somewhere in-between.

I could calculate the confidence interval at $\sqrt{0.05}$ for offset and slope and then visualise the extrema as described above, to get an effective 5% probability range.  But I'm almost certainly reinventing the wheel here.  What is a suitable way of visualising the uncertainty in a regression line — slope and offset?

For reference, Pythons statsmodels.api.OLS summaries my regression fit as below.  In my real world example, I use a weighted least squares, because I have errors on my y-values (and I am considering orthogonal distance regression as I have errors on my x-values too, but I am neglecting those for now).

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.026
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.023
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     9.673
Date:                Mon, 06 Apr 2015   Prob (F-statistic):            0.00202
Time:                        18:14:55   Log-Likelihood:                 1223.1
No. Observations:                 370   AIC:                            -2442.
Df Residuals:                     368   BIC:                            -2434.
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.1065      0.032      3.343      0.001         0.044     0.169
x1            -0.1038      0.033     -3.110      0.002        -0.169    -0.038
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       23.030   Durbin-Watson:                   1.484
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               45.433
Skew:                          -0.350   Prob(JB):                     1.36e-10
Kurtosis:                       4.567   Cond. No.                         138.
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Have you thought about using an [elliptical confidence region](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86277/7071)?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I can see how I would visualise an elliptical confidence region around a simple data point — but such a confidence region around a regression line would be an 3-dimensional ellipsoid.  Of course, I could add a separate figure visualising the slope and uncertainty of my regression line with an ellipse...

Comment: I see only 2 parameters in your output. Am I missing something? The ellipse is the CI for the slope and the intercept, not the data.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Yes, the ellipse is on the slope and the intercept.  But I want to show the model (the linear regression) in the same graph as the data.

Comment: Are you just asking how to get a 95% confidence or prediction interval for E[Y|X] = a + b*x1, where a is the constant and b is the slope?

Comment: I think so, yes — I have the 95% confidence interval on `a` and on `b`.

Comment: Does python provide you with the covariance between the x1 coefficient and constant?

Comment: [It appears so, if I understand correctly](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.cov_params.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.cov_params).  That should help me draw a confidence band like in [xans answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/145156/12615), I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be looking for what Wikipedia calls "[Confidence Bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_and_prediction_bands)". The band edges are curves instead of lines because the joint probability.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is a good starting point for further reading!  I just need to figure out how to draw those given my parameters and the covariance between them.  Seems [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17559408/974555) gets me close.

Answer (score 4):

A sometimes useful alternative to the confidence band is to show the estimated line together with bootstrapped lines. Here is a simple, simulated example:

[image: Estimeted LS line with bootstrapped lines]

```
EDIT
```

Bootstrapping regression can be done in different ways, for instance:

1. Resampling (with replacement) from the rows of the design matrix. **This is what I have done here**. A robust option, is valid even when assumptions like constant variance do not hold. But a philosophical problem, it does not really condition on the covariables, see [What is the difference between conditioning on regressors vs. treating them as fixed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144826/what-is-the-difference-between-conditioning-on-regressors-vs-treating-them-as-f/192746#192746).
2. Resmpling residuals. More dependent on assumptions like constant variance, but true to conditioning on predictors.
3. Parametric bootstrap, more of a bayesian flavour.

It could be interesting to try all tree and see how much of a difference it makes.

R code for the simulation:

```
set.seed(7*11*13) # My public seed

a <- 1.0; b <- 0.8

x <- rep( seq(-5, 5, length.out=11), 3)
Y <- a + b*x + rnorm(x, sd=3)
df <- data.frame(x, Y)
n <- NROW(df)
mod.0 <- lm(Y ~ x, data=df)

plot(x, Y, col="blue2",  pch=16)
abline(mod.0, col="red2", lwd=2)

for (i in 1:20) {
    ind <- sample(1:n, n, replace=TRUE)
    abline( lm(Y ~ x, data=df[ind, ]), col="pink")
}

title("Estimated line with bootstrapped lines")
```

Comment: Can you add something on how those bootstrapped lines are defined?  Just random draws from the probability distribution, what I seem to infer from your R code?

Comment: @gerrit: Have a look at the edits.

Answer (score 3):

Python might give you this output, but it's pretty easy from first principles.

You want the 95% confidence interval for $a+bx$, where $a$ and $b$ are estimated with the data with some error, which introduces the uncertainty.

The 95% confidence interval for the expected value of y given a particular value of $x$ is the prediction from the model for that $x$ $\pm$ 1.96*prediction error. That is also why $0.1065 + 1.96 \cdot 0.032=.169,$ the upper bound of the 95%CI for the constant.

So we need to get the standard error of the prediction. You may remember that $$Var(a+bx)=Var(a) + Var(b)\cdot x^2+2\cdot x \cdot Cov(a,b).$$ This formula can be found [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables). The standard error is just the square root of the variance. This yields:
          $$(0.1065 -0.1038 \cdot x) \pm 1.96 \cdot (0.032^2 + (x \cdot 0.033)^2 + 2\cdot x \cdot Cov(a,b))^{1/2}.$$

You did not show the covariance between the slope and the intercept, so I could not plug it in.